# all results from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show all results from a database which have the same category.

I have managed to print one row from the database just wondering how i do this for the rest?

here is my code

```
<?php 

$catagory=$_GET["q"];


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","cl49-XXX","XXX");
if (!$con) 
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

@mysql_select_db("cl49-vogalcms", $con)or die( "Unable to select database");


$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE catagory  = '$catagory' ")or die('You need enter a catagoryE ' );
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$prodname=$row['prodname'];
$prodID=$row['prodID'];


echo"Catagory: $catagory <br /> ID $prodID<br /> name $prodname";

if ($swt==0) {$swt=1;} else {$swt=0;} 

?>
```

Comment: mysql_* extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

Comment: And, categorically, it's 'category'

Answer (score 4):

You can run a loop like following:

```
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result); 
if ($rowCount > 0) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $prodname=$row['prodname'];
    $prodID=$row['prodID'];
    echo"Catagory: $catagory <br /> ID $prodID<br /> name $prodname";
  }
} else {
  echo "No Products are available";
}
```

A couple of other points to note are:

1. Do not suppress errors with `@mysql_select_db`. Since you already have `or die(...`, remove the `@` in front of `mysql_select_db`.  This is because you want to see the errors if they occurred.
2. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` as `mysql` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for this. How would i show a message if no products are available?

Comment: @user2643837, Please see the updated code in my answer.  You should be able to add a call to `mysql_num_rows` and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the result set.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $prodname=$row['prodname'];
 $prodID=$row['prodID'];
 echo"Catagory: $catagory <br /> ID $prodID<br /> name $prodname";
}
```